# HTML Form With Multiple buttons - Not calling Jquery function

Tags: jquery, html

Am having the below form in HTML

```
<form id="test" name="test">
<button id="save" class="small"><i class="icon-plus"></i>save</button>  //KickStart
<button id="edit" class="small"><i class="icon-plus"></i>edit</button>
 <input value=1 type="text" name=Col1 class="Hide">
 <input value=2 type="text" name=Col2 class="Hide">

</form>
```

JQuery function to be called on button click

```
$(document).on("click", "#edit", function (e) {

    return false;
});
```

But when i click on edit button form Submits and not calling the Jquery function as expected.

Maybe I am missing some property of the form ?

Comment: Can you post your HTML where you've included jQuery? Also, is the event bound within `document.ready`?

Comment: Am not getting ur 1st one ! And for second question No ! Separate event not in document.ready

Comment: You could use the attribute `type="button" ` for the buttons html. This will stop it from submitting.

Comment: For the 1st one, i mean the HTML code (script tag) where you've referenced jQuery library. As for the second, what @Razz has answered.

Comment: I [replicated your code](http://jsbin.com/usotul/1/edit) and do not experience the problem you describe.

Comment: @Quentin Am not sure what am doing wrong! But Putting the event in document.ready fixed it? Am clueless. Any idea ?

Comment: @Peru I suggest reading this: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @Jeemusu Any idea on Comments ? Am not sure why it is not working for me wen i have outside document.ready

Comment: @Peru Basically, if you don't wrap your code in a document.ready then it's possible that it will be executed before the DOM (Page structure) is ready (built). If it is executed before the DOM is ready then it will have no effect as it will be unable to find your #edit element. Wrapping it in document.ready explicitly tells your code to wait until the DOM is ready before executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to wait for the DOM to get ready before binding an event to any element.

All you gotta do is put your code inside a

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", "#edit", function (e) {
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I would recommend using `e.preventDefault();` instead of `return false;`

Comment: And to also use `$('#edit').on('click', function(){...});` instead of document.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following code in the header, you need to use `$(function(){}).` This will run code after load page.

```
$(function(){
  $("#edit").click(function (e) {
    alert("a");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#edit").click(function(e) {
         alert("edit button clicked!");
         return false;
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the preventDefault() function:

```
$(document).on("click", "#edit", function (e) {
    alert("Hi");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/AbP8Z/ and http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault